# TypeError: a float is required

Tags: python

Boa noite. Estou com o seguinte código em Python que, quando calcula a variável `h`, aparece o citado erro:

```
x=[]
y=[]
erro=[]
h=[]
x=0.1
y=0.1
for i in range (40):
    x=x**2-0.391*x
    y=y*(y-0.391)
    import math
    erro.append(math.fabs((x-y)/2))
erro.remove(0)
h.append(math.log10(erro))
```

Comment: O objeto `erro` é uma lista de 40 posições e você está tentando calcular o *log* desta lista. A função `log10` espera um parâmetro do tipo `float`, não uma lista.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`erro` é do tipo lista e você está tentando puxar `log10` de uma lista.

Fiz uma modificação, agora ele vai varrer a lista `erro` e vai adicionar cada `log10` de cada erro na lista `h`. Veja como ficou:

```
import math
erro=[]
h=[]
x=0.1
y=0.1
for i in range (40):
    x=x**2-0.391*x
    y=y*(y-0.391)
    erro.append(math.fabs((x-y)/2))
erro.remove(0)
for x in erro:
  h.append(math.log10(x))
```

E por favor, por padrão, ponha o `import` na entrada do código.

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda.

Quando ele calcula o log gostaria que excluísse os 4 primeiros valores. Tentei colocar 
for x in erro(4,40):
h.append(math.log10(x))

Apareceu o seguinte erro: 'list' object is not callable

Teria como eu fazer isso?

Comment: Fatie a lista.

h[4:]

Esse comando elimina os quatro primeiros elementos da lista final.

E por favor, se eu respondi sua pergunta, apenas confirme no post, é importante.

Comment: Estou com mais um probleminha, vocês poderiam me ajudar?
import numpy as np
x=np.ones((4,1))
for k in range (5,45):
    x[k]=5.5369*x[k-1]*(x[k-2])**2+0.1931*x[k-3]
print(x)

Gostaria que em x[k-1], como k começaria em k, seria x[4], ai seria os dados de entrada, ai quando fosse x[5], nesse caso seria o primeiro valor calculado

Comment: Cria lá uma nova pergunta.